# Is there a proof for the Central Limit Theorem via some fixed point theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, fixed-point-theorems

This question arose in my mind when I learned that the Gaussian is a fixed point for the Fourier transform. On the other hand, in e.g. the Banach fixed point theorem we have convergence to a fixed point.

So are these two things (CLT and Gaussian being a fixed point of the Fourier transform) somehow connected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you may want to look at [Stein's method](http://theory.stanford.edu/~valiant/teaching/CS362/cs362_steins.pdf) (which in particular yields a way to prove the Central Limit Theorem).

(cf. also [Wikipedia's entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_method) on Stein's method)